# Cannot send parameter from touchesEnded

Tags: iphone, objective-c

im trying to send a parameter from my touchesEnded handler like so...

```
    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGFloat deltaX = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.x - currentPosition.x);
    CGFloat deltaY = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.y - currentPosition.y);
    if (deltaX >= 0.3 && deltaY <= 100) { //horizontal swipe detected

               [self performSelector:@selector(refreshCover:)
                   withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
        if (gestureStartPoint.x < currentPosition.x) { //swipe right
            [self refreshCover:@"backward"];
            NSLog(@"swipe backward");
        } else { //swipe left
            [self refreshCover:@"forward"];
            NSLog(@"swipe forward");
        }       
    }
}
```

then in refreshCover, i just have :

```
    - (void)refreshCover:(NSString*)direction {

    NSLog(@"direction: %@", direction);
}
```

when a user swipes, refreshCover is called, but the direction parameter is not getting passed.  if i call [self refreshCover:@"forward"] from anywhere else, the parameter is passed without problems.

any ideas? thanks in advance.

Comment: what is [self performSelector:...] supposed to be doing? Do the logs print out?

Comment: Why are you calling refreshCover: using performSelector (with nil object) before the if-statement?

Comment: Why not just use a [`UISwipeGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this code

```
[self performSelector:@selector(refreshCover:)
               withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

The performSelector will call the function. I think this code is not needed since you are calling the function individually

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. left that line from an older code... wow can't believe i spent hours trying to figure it out and missed that! hahaha

Comment: You are welcome. Welcome to SO. Try to accept answers if it solves your solution. :)